# Absolute file path using react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Am using Input type 'file' for browsing files in from my machine using react js application , After select the file from my local i want to get the absolute path of my file , ex : `C://something/something.png` like this . so i searched on many sites , all are telling that **from UI we cant access our machine!!** .Ok fine , now my doubt here is then how can i achieve that . can someone help/give_ur_suggestion me on this.
thanks in advance .

Comment: This question as it stands is too broad to answer properly. It is true that browsers have limited filesystem access for security reasons. My recommendation would be to look at platforms like [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) which allow you to build cross platform desktop apps using HTML/CSS/JS. Your usecase would be a good fit for that paradigm as you will have access to the filesystem in that scenario.

Comment: Well as your searching told you, you can't access local files and their information from the browser. You can either run the actual app on their machine (via, say, building it with electron as Chriag mentioned above), or they will have to enter any relevant information themselves into the app in the browser.

Comment: Tnx for ur feedback . let me try those now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **relative path**.

In practice, you have to put all your assets, source code, ressources, etc. in one directory to ease deployment. Indeed, when you deploy your code, the server is not aware of your computer. With relative paths, it can resolve the path to your ressources.

You can read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) the difference betwen relative path and absolute path:

> Absolute and relative paths. An absolute or full path points to the same location in a file system, regardless of the current working directory. To do that, it must include the root directory. By contrast, a relative path starts from some given working directory, avoiding the need to provide the full absolute path.